# InputStreamReader or Console for Java I/O

Tags: java, console, bufferedinputstream

To get user input in Java which is the better method?

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

or 
by use of Console--> `Console c = System.console();`

what is the difference between the two and which one is to be used. Or is there any other better method other than these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Console was introduced recently to Java (Java 6) to make reading and writing to the command line easier. Therefore, I would use Console.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class to get user input from console

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

in.next();
int i = in.nextInt();
float f = in.nextFloat();
double d = in.nextDouble();    
String s = in.nextLine();
```

and other beautiful methods

but between these two I recommend you Console

Answer (score 0):

they are pretty much the same, however, the Console has additional methods for securely reading information from the user (eg. password) and returns a more intuitive result for whether the underlying platform actually does support console operations or is launched in a non-interactive environment

Answer (score 0):

IMHO they are total diferent. As the doc says:

> Methods to access the character-based
>   console device, if any, associated
>   with the current Java virtual machine.

So the implementation is OS specific and not platform independent (there could be or not).

With Consol even you can not read from stdin:

```
echo 123 | java Test
```

If Test is using Console it won't work. So the user MUST give input from the console.