# Using throws java.io.IOException and getting System.in.read(); to access a case via an integer

Tags: java, throws

I only need help with the input part. If the user inputs a number I need the program to read and output a case that equals the number that was input.

//This program will display the months of the year

```
public class MonthsOfTheYear {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws java.io.IOException{

        int month;

        System.out.println("Please enter a Month Number: ");

        month = (int) System.in.read(); //Get an integer

        switch (month) {
        case 1:  System.out.println("January");
        break;
        case 2:  System.out.println("February");
        break;
        case 3:  System.out.println("March");
        break;
        case 4:  System.out.println("April");
        break;
        case 5:  System.out.println("May");
        break;
        case 6:  System.out.println("June");
        break;
        case 7:  System.out.println("July");
        break;
        case 8:  System.out.println("August");
        break;
        case 9:  System.out.println("September");
        break;
        case 10: System.out.println("October");
        break;
        case 11: System.out.println("November");
        break;
        case 12: System.out.println("December");
        break;
        default: System.out.println("Invalid Month");
        break;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual question? I don't understand what you're asking for specifically.

Comment: this might be what you are looking for 
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273449/what-does-system-in-read-actually-return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html) to read your System.in

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
month = input.nextInt();
```

Output:

```
Please enter a Month Number: 
1
January
```

See [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506077/how-to-read-integer-value-from-the-standard-input-in-java)

Edit:

as noahz pointed out there is a `Console` class that covers the same functionality. For an idea of the difference between the two, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039762/why-do-we-use-console-class).

Comment: Console was introduced in Java 6 specifically to make reading input from the command line easier. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602436/inputstreamreader-or-console-for-java-i-o

Answer (score 1):

Try  using  the  Console  class  instead: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html to  obtain  user  input,  then  convert the  String  to a  number  with  `Integer.parseInt(String)`

Also,  be aware that the  next  version of  Java (8) will  support  Strings in `case`  blocks.

Comment: ... by  clicking the  checkbox image.

Answer (score 1):

```
class vehicle
{
   int passengers;
   int fuelcap;
   int mpg;
}

import java.io.*;
class Vehicle_Demo
{

   public static void main (String args[]) throws java.io.IOException
   {
      vehicle obj1 = new vehicle();
      obj1.passengers=12;
      obj1.fuelcap=9;
      obj1.mpg=78;

      System.out.println(obj1.passengers, obj1.fuelcap, obj1.mpg);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use TextIO Input Functions

This is better than scanner input

You need to compile [TextIO.java](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/source/TextIO.java) fist as a prerequisite so that TextIO.class must be found in the same folder.

use this input function instead:

month = TextIO.getChar();

Please let me know if you have problems on this method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure it will still work with "system.in.read". You're switch cases do not have single quotes around the input you want to be processed. If you want case one to be run when you type '1' your case should be case '1', not case 1.

Answer (score 0):

There problem here was Java have cast a character to an integer, therefore you get an ASCII value.
 
For instance, when you type 5 you've got 53 in ASCII. Check it taking the variable value in `System.out.println();` 
 

 
I've tried to solve that changing month to a char type and then passing a char value to the switch control. But the problem is, getting `System.in.read();` method you just can get a single character. At last you just can select between 1 to 9.
 

 
I suspect the solution is using a buffer reader. Until then, I leave you here my code:

```
public class MonthsOfTheYear {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws java.io.IOException{

        char month;

        System.out.println("Please enter a Month Number: ");

        month = (char) System.in.read(); //Get an integer
        //System.out.println("Actual value of :" + month);

        switch (month) {
        case '1':  System.out.println("January");
        break;
        case '2':  System.out.println("February");
        break;
        case '3':  System.out.println("March");
        break;
        case '4':  System.out.println("April");
        break;
        case '5':  System.out.println("May");
        break;
        case '6':  System.out.println("June");
        break;
        case '7':  System.out.println("July");
        break;
        case '8':  System.out.println("August");
        break;
        case '9':  System.out.println("September");
        break;
        /*case '10': System.out.println("October");
        break;
        case '11': System.out.println("November");
        break;
        case '12': System.out.println("December");
        break;*/
        default: System.out.println("Invalid Month");
        break;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```